# How to show BigDecimal number as human readable when using ActiveSupport::TestCase

Tags: ruby, bigdecimal, awesomeprint

When I'm using `ActiveSupport::TestCase` tests that are failed shows message like this:

```
  2) Failure:
ArrayTest#test_example [/Users/ironsand/dev/my_project/test/core_ext/array_test.rb:6]:
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-#<BigDecimal:7fb947c749a0,'0.94E0',9(18)>
+#<BigDecimal:7fb947c7f5a8,'0.95E0',9(45)>
```

I want to show the value `0.94` instead of `<BigDecimal:7fb947c749a0,'0.94E0',9(18)>`.
In rails cosole or in `pry` I'm using `awesome_print`.

Is there a way to activate `awesome_print` for result of the test?
I don't insist on using `awesome_print`, if there is another way to show the number more readable, I gonna happily use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a message to to the assert statement

```
message = "Expected #{expected_number.to_f} but actual number is #{actual_number.to_f}"
assert_equal expected_number, actual_number, message
```

Also, you didn't ask this, but if you are trying to compare two decimal numbers, you probably want to use assert_in_delta to see that the numbers are close rather than exact.